# Open yeoman diff in IDE

Tags: yeoman, yeoman-generator-angular

During the yeoman generation if a file has been changed you can compare the changes with the previous file ( the diff ) by selecting `d` from the options.

```
 Overwrite foo.js? (Ynaxdh)
```

Is there any way to open those changes in an IDE like visual studio code perhaps?